# How to add integer NSArrays objects with 2 dimention to NSMutableArray in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a NSMutableArray and want to add a 2 dimensional NSArray with integer parameters to it each time. But after use that values their IDs not show as Integers.And I tried `@[i,j]` too but it didn't work. Here is my code :

```
resault = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:40];

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
   for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
   {
      [resault addObject:@[@(i),@(j)]];
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the ouput you are getting and what do you expect?

Comment: @user1000 resault[0][0] return a ID not Integer

Comment: @SaMiGiMiX still not sure to understand what you want to return, use real value to express it

Comment: According to above code you are storing an NSNumber in a slot, so to get integer, you need to use [resault[0][0] integerValue]

Comment: Please show the example output you want

Comment: @user1000 for example: i add  ** @[@(1),@(2)] ** then when I use ** result[0][1] ** it must return 2 but it returns 18. And the error is incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'id'.

Comment: @user1000 thank you. And how to set Integer at first instead of NSNumber ?

Comment: You cannot insert integer directly to an NSMutableArray because NSMutableArray constains only objects and integer is not an object, its a  premitive  data type found in c, hence numbers are stored as NSNumber objects

Comment: @user1000 Best answer and help. Thank You

Comment: No worries, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Use this code -

```
NSMutableArray*resault = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:40];
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    NSMutableArray*array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:40];
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
        [array addObject:@[@(i),@(j)]];
    }
    [resault addObject:array];
}
```

Comment: I want to count my resault later but with this code I can't  .. .

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
NSMutableArray * ma = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++){
        [ma addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%i",i,d]];
    }
}
NSLog(@"id is %@", ma);
```

Cycle through the I loop, then the D loop and add into the array as NSString objects. If you need them as NSNumbers, just convert them later. If you are counting up from 0 to n, you can use a single for loop (e.g. from 0 to 100 would work in the example above), while nesting for loops works better if you're using non numerical IDs.

If you want to keep the 0 character in front of IDs below ten, using a single for loop:

```
NSMutableArray * ma = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){

    [ma addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",i]];
}
NSLog(@"id is %@", ma);
```

Using your method:

```
NSMutableArray * ma = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++){
        [ma addObject:@[@(i),@(d)]];
    }
}

int thirtiethI = [ma[30][0] intValue];
int thirtiethD = [ma[30][1] intValue];
NSLog(@"thirtieth: %i %i", thirtiethI, thirtiethD);
```

Comment: i think it's a smarter way, tnx

Answer (score 1):

resault = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:40];

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
   for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
   {
       [resault addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
           [NSNumber numberwithInt:i],
           [NSNumber numberWithInt:j],
           nil]
       ];
   }
}
```

You can then access the i,j pairs by running through the result array and extracting the stored NSArray and getting the first and second objects sorted therein.

Comment: tnx it's another way

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to understand the int, float these basic types can not be deposited into the array

So when you add it @(i), this means [NSNumber numberWithInt: i]

The array is the type of NSNumber

If you want to take it out

```
int result = [resault [30] [0] intValue];
```

Comment: tnx for help it's true